# Keep old values of a List<SelectItem> for a back to the previous

Tags: list, jsf, selectonemenu

i don't know if i can clearly explain my problem but i will try :)

I have lot of folder , and each folder depends of an other.

Example :

Document, Pictures , Other depends of root.
Text depends of Documents.
PNG,GIF,JPG depends of Pictures.

The first time i display the list i have :
DOCUMENT
OTHER
PICTURES

When i select for example PICTURES, the list will display PNG,GIF,JPG.
It is always the same list.
And i don't see how come back to the previous list.
I tryed to create a other list for keep the old value but it doesn't work, or i dont know where put the assignement of that value.

```
    public List<SelectItem> getListSelectItemFolder() {
    if(mListSelectItemFolder == null)
    {
        mListSelectItemFolder = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        List<Folder> lListFolder = getFolderManager().searchFolder(getFolderManager().getRootFolderId(mSessionBean.getUser(), mSessionBean.isNotUserAdminGe()), mSessionBean.getUser().getFirm(), mSessionBean.isNotUserAdminGe());
        mListSelectItemFolder.add(new SelectItem(getFolderManager().getById(getFolderManager().getRootFolderId(mSessionBean.getUser(), mSessionBean.isNotUserAdminGe())), "root"));
        for (Folder lFolder : lListFolder) {
            if(lFolder.getId()>=0)
            {
                mListSelectItemFolder.add(new SelectItem(lFolder, lFolder.getName()));
            }
        }
        return mListSelectItemFolder;
    }
    if(getDocument().getFolder()!=null)
    {
        List<Folder> lListFolder = getFolderManager().searchFolder(mDocument.getFolder().getId(), mSessionBean.getUser().getFirm(), mSessionBean.isNotUserAdminGe());
        if(lListFolder.size()>0)
        {
            mListSelectItemFolder = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (Folder lFolder : lListFolder) {
                if(lFolder.getId()>=0)
                {
                    mListSelectItemFolder.add(new SelectItem(lFolder, lFolder.getName()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mListSelectItemFolder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

up please =)
I have created a button, here is the code :

```
    public void backButton()
{
    if(mListSelectItemFolder==null || ((Folder) mListSelectItemFolder.get(0).getValue()).getIdDep()==0 )
    {
        //if the list is null or the parent folder is the first one name rootone (id=0)
        mListSelectItemFolder=null;
    }
    else
    {
        if(mFolderManager.getById(mFolderManager.getById(((Folder) mListSelectItemFolder.get(0).getValue()).getIdDep()).getIdDep()).getIdDep()==0)
        {
            //case where we gonna go back in the first level, the start folder
            mListSelectItemFolder=null;
        }
        else
        {
            getDocument().setFolder(((Folder) mFolderManager.getById(((Folder)mListSelectItemFolder.get(0).getValue()).getIdDep())));
        }
    }
}
```